# How do I reset a cookie connected to an already existing express session?

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, cookies, session-cookies

I am using Mongo Sessions to save user data (no logins). When a user logs in for the first time I create a new session on the db and set a cookie on the client, the session information is now saved in localStorage. I want to use the same session per user, so their session object also stores things like 'Last Seen' , 'Socket ID' etc. Things that change often.

The problem is when a user client deletes the cookie (by any chance) a new cookie + session is created so all that data is 'gone'.
My question is 'How do I set a new cookie that points to an already existing session'?

```
// Anytime there is a (re)connection save the socketID to the session

io.on('connection', function(socket: i.Socket) {

  socket.handshake.session!.lastSeen = new Date();
  socket.handshake.session!.socketID = socket.id;
  socket.handshake.session!.save((err: Error) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error in saving session! => ', err);
    }  
  });
  // Now each session has it's socketID!
});
```

Thank you for your help, I *need* this. You can also suggest other ways I can do this.

Answer (score 0):

How about, checking existing session of the user, while creating a new session for an user? If exists, use that session id in the cookie.

But, `lastSeen`, `socketID` sounds like application logic. These can be maintained in database along with the user data.

Comment: Yes, that's the thing, the sessions serve as user data